# PHP - Do something if no errors/warnings occur in set of expressions

Tags: php, xml

I have a page that will basically be used to concatenate a bunch of xml files, it will act as glue that binds them together. There's a small chance the xml files that are being combined might not be well formed because the user will have access.

I'm trying to basically rewrite a live file *if* there are no warnings / errors thrown in a specific set of code.

So far I have:

```
try {
    $first = simplexml_load_file( 'file.xml' );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    $write = false;
}

if ( !$write ) { 
// write to live file.
}
```

This obviously catches error exceptions, but sometimes function invocations can return warnings and not errors per se, what can I use to catch errors, basically only write if no warnings and errors have been thrown in the try block?

Example of a warning being thrown:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() parser error : Start tag expected, '<'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look for other "symptoms" of a failed read. From the `simplexml_load_file` manual entry:

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document. **On errors, it will return FALSE.**

So, use it like this:

```
$first = simplexml_load_file( 'file.xml' );

if ($first == false) {
    echo "File couldn't be loaded";
    exit(); // abort normal program execution, redirect or what have you
}

// continue as normal
```

Almost all functions return some sort of `false` in case of an error. You shouldn't use manual "error parsing" except for very special cases. This isn't one of them.

Comment: yeah, but this gets tedious if you have lots of instances, no? even if you combine all the checking into one expression. i'm not worried about performance issues either.

Comment: Do you mean `if ($var == false)` is more tedious than handling exceptions or output buffering and string parsing? This is by far the simplest method if your function helpfully returns a `false`. If you do this multiple times, gather all results in an array and check if there are any `false` entries in the array once at the end. Or do it in a loop.

Comment: It's just that it's a whole slew of expressions, not just assigning a simple identifier to something that coerces to true, I'm doing loops through it, and I'm doing a lot of operation which is why I don't want to have 10-15 or so checks.

Comment: Please post more of your code and why you think it's so hard to integrate.

Answer (score 3):

A few things come to mind for this situation. if you will always have warnings enabled (not a great idea for a production server) you can always use the output buffering functions to check if there was any text sent out

```
ob_start();
... //code
$str = ob_get_contents();
if (! empty($string))
{
  // a warning was thrown.
}
```

The better way is to [define an error handler](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler)  for warnings and do whatever you want with them:

```
set_error_handler("my_warning_handler", E_WARNING);

function my_warning_handler($errno, $errstr) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an error handler, and raise exceptions from there. Then catch them as usual.